# Is there a way to easily encode a message without a computer on either end?

Tags: algorithm-design, classical-cipher, pen-and-paper

I enjoy making notes and passing them to my friends, and I *also* like making them encrypted for no reason. My friends enjoy it too, but it's a bit annoying to use the Caesar cipher for everything because its repetitive and takes forever. Is there a better pen-and-paper way of encrypting messages?

Comment: takes forever? what do you want to do with pen-and-paper, parallel pen-and-paper computation? At the end, classical ciphers operates on characters and you have to deal with them one-by-one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the classical crypto algorithms used in the pre computer era can be doable with pen and paper!! Lot of there are in the list see here http://practicalcryptography.com/ciphers/classical-era/ . Try Vigenere and change you keys frequently.